# run multiple tasks in parallel using C#.net 2.0

Tags: winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker, c#-2.0

I need to perform 2 tasks in parallel. One will load data in the GUI, till then I want to run a progress bar continuously in front of user. I tried BackgroundWorker but it is giving me some Thread synchronization error. Can somebody suggest me any other best way of doing same.

Code:
backgroundWorker1  initialization:

```
        backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);

        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

error coming on following line:

```
    XmlDocumentHierarchy _remoteObj = new XmlDocumentHierarchy(comboBox2.Text, "username", "password");
```

is:

```
   "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'comboBox2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."
```

Comment: What thread error you receive? Maybe you update progress not in GUI thread? Can you post some code?

Comment: added some code and line where error is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying access `comboBox2.Text` in thread other than GUI thread (background worker thread). If you using only one property in background worker thread, than you can pass `comboBox2.Text' to background worker method:

```cs
if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(comboBox2.Text);
}
```

In `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` procedure you can read property in following way:

```cs
void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    String comboBoxText = (String)e.Argument;
    XmlDocumentHierarchy _remoteObj = new XmlDocumentHierarchy(comboBoxText, "username", "password");
}
```

If you accessing more than one property from GUI controls you can create simple class to pass all necessary data to your background worker method.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access GUI thread from BackgroundWorker thread, you can easily invoke your methods in the GUI thread like this:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Thread thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BackGroundThread));
        thr.Start();
    }

    void BackGroundThread() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
        {
            // The line below will be run in the GUI thread with no synchronization issues
            BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { this.Text = "Processed " + i.ToString() + "%"; });                
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }
```